# convert SHA256 from nodejs to java

Tags: java, node.js, hash, digital-signature, sha256

Below is the code snippet that I am using the generate the hash in nodejs. could anyone please help me out to get the same functionality in java. where `data` is the data I want to hash and `privKey` is the private key.

```
const {
  createSign,
  createVerify,
} = require('crypto');


const sign = createSign('SHA256')
sign.write(JSON.stringify(data))
sign.end()
const signature = sign.sign(privKey,"hex")
```

Comment: It's not just generating a hash - it's generating a signature. What kind of signature do you want? What private key format are you using? There are lots of examples online, such as [this one for RSA](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/how-to-create-sha256-rsa-signature-using-java.html) It would really help if you'd show the research you've performed so far, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet, I tried with the link shared by you but there is mismatch in the signature between the nodejs snippet and java

Comment: Well that may well be because Node isn't using RSA. You should find out what kind of signature it's actually trying to create, and update your question with more information.